# Need help calculating the integral $\iint_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-(|2x-y| + |2y-x|)}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\text{I'm asked to calculate}\quad
\iint_{{\mathbb R}^{2}}
{\rm e}^{-\left\vert\,2x - y\,\right\vert\ -\ \left\vert\,2y - x\,\right\vert}
\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y.
$$

I've substituted $u = 2x-y, v = 2y-x$ and came up with:

$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-(|u| + |v|)}\times|J|\,du\,dv = 3\times \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(u +v)}\,du\,dv +3 \times \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{u + v}\,du\,dv$$

After integrating I get that the integral doesn't converge. What did I do wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you say that the integral doesn't converge???

Comment: My mistake, I plugged in wrong values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $$e^{-(u+v)} = e^{-u}e^{-v},$$ we easily find $$\int_{u=0}^\infty \int_{v=0}^\infty e^{-(u+v)} \, dv \, du = \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-u} \, du \int_{v=0}^\infty e^{-v} \, dv = 1.$$  Here is an image of the surface.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! What allows you to split the integral and multiply? Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Once you've written it the way you have you don't need anything else, but I suppose you could justify this being equal to the integral over a quadrant with Tonelli then Fubini.

Answer (score 0):

Since $u = 2x-y, v = 2y-x$, we have $|J|=\frac{1}{3}$.

$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-(|2x-y| + |2y-x|)}dxdy=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-(|u| + |v|)}\times|J|dudv=\frac{1}{3}\iint_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-(|u| + |v|)}dudv$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\left(2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}du\right)\left(2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-v}dv\right)=\frac{4}{3}$$